# How to avoid the full path being shown under an embedded document in Microsoft Word 2003?

Tags: filenames, microsoft-word-2003, embedding

When I embed a document inside another using `Inset>Object>Create from file`, the file is shown with the full path underneath, truncated by the available space so it invariably looks awful.

[image]

Is there another method that avoids this and just shows the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can right click the object, select *Packager Shell Object Object*, then *Convert*.

[image: Context menu]

Click *Change Icon* then edit the caption to whatever you want to be displayed.

[image: Changing the caption]